# Custom Post Type not showing in main loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, query

I have created a custom post type 'courses' but it is not showing up when I do a var_dump of get_post_types(). here is my code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types' );
function create_post_types() {
    $courseargs = array(
            'labels' => array(
                        'name' => 'Courses',
                        'singular_name' => 'Course',
                       ),
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'courses' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'taxonomies'         => array( 'category' ),
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'menu_position'      => null,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
    );
register_post_type( 'courses', $courseargs );
}

// add the featured image thumbnail to the admin courses column
add_filter( 'manage_courses_posts_columns', 'add_img_column' );
add_action( 'manage_courses_posts_custom_column' , 'manage_img_column', 10, 2 );

// size the thumbnail
add_image_size( 'admin-list-thumb', 80, 80, false );

function add_img_column($columns) {
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'author' => 'Author',
        'categories' => 'Categories',
        'tags' => 'Tags',
        'comments' => '<span class="vers"><div title="Comments" class="comment-grey-bubble"></div></span>',
        'featured_thumb' => 'Thumbnail',
        'date' => 'Date'
    );
    return $columns;
}

function manage_img_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
    case 'featured_thumb':
        echo '<a href="' . get_edit_post_link() . '">';
        echo the_post_thumbnail( 'admin-list-thumb' );
        echo '</a>';
        break;
    }
}

// Show posts of 'post', 'page' and 'courses' post types on home page
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
  if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'courses' ) );
  return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

var_dump(get_post_types());
```

This is what the var_dump gives me.

```
array(8) {
  ["post"]=>
  string(4) "post"
  ["page"]=>
  string(4) "page"
  ["attachment"]=>
  string(10) "attachment"
  ["revision"]=>
  string(8) "revision"
  ["nav_menu_item"]=>
  string(13) "nav_menu_item"
  ["custom_css"]=>
  string(10) "custom_css"
  ["customize_changeset"]=>
  string(19) "customize_changeset"
  ["oembed_cache"]=>
  string(12) "oembed_cache"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `var_dump`, "courses" isn't showing up because the `var_dump` is running outside of any action. So it gets triggered before the "init" action runs, which is where the post type is registered.

Regarding the main loop, I pasted your code into the default Twenty Seventeen theme's functions.php file, and added a course via the dashboard, and it showed up on the homepage for me.

Comment: Is there a way I can test to see if it is showing up other than using var_dump?

Comment: If you put the var_dump inside your add_my_post_types_to_query function, that should work.